# java.exe location does not match path

Tags: java, path

I've spent some time on this and cannot come up with a solution. I've set my java path to the appropriate one:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45 <br>
```

however, when I do a "which java" command in cmd I get the wrong path. It returns a previous java path (cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/java to be specific).
Running a `java -version` returns the previous java version.
I've already tried restarting my machine after changing the paths.

I see no trace of the old path in any of my environment variables either. Has anyone come across this problem?


Update: Forgot to mention that I updated PATH appropriately as well. Also, "java -version" returns

```
c:/aim % java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
```

There is no trace of java directory 1.7.0_79 in any of my env vars.

Comment: The JAVA_HOME variable is not the same as the PATH variable

Comment: @khelwood I didn't mention it, but I updated PATH as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another Java on your path, and it is placed before your new JDK in the path. Example path:

```
PATH=c:\Windows\system32;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\
```

Switch that to something like this:

```
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;c:\Windows\system32
```

This way, your new Java version will be in your path before the one in SYSTEM32.

Also, check your user path vs. system path.

Comment: Moving up my java on PATH definitely helped (not sure how if there was no other reference anywhere else) out. However, my issue isn't over. Seems like the problem lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME is a only environment variable. You need to check which Java path set on your PATH variable. To resolve this issue you need to set `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin` in your `PATH` variable. Also make sure you will append this Java path variable in beginning. like set

`PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;%PATH%`

Comment: Not sure if you answered before my update, but I have already done this.

Comment: Can you provide your path variable value?

Answer (score 0):

You must have the directory containing `java.exe` on path, and first of another directory containing other `java.exe` version.

You have already defined a `JAVA_HOME` variable, make sure to add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` on beginning of definition of `%PATH%`.

Note that maybe you also to restart the current console for having the new `%PATH%`definition set correctly

Comment: The previous java version is 1.7.0_79, there is no trace of this directory in any of my env vars.

Comment: There is a system java version installed on windows OS under the system path `Windows\system32`. Put your java bin at the beginning of PATH and it finally should work.